# The attribute 'endpointConfiguration' cannot be specified on element 'endpoint' when attribute 'kind' is not specified

Tags: wcf

title is the exception message from wcf service client when i create object of proxy class

i have simple wcf service with

```
<security mode="Transport"> and <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
```

this is the app.config of client

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NoValidationBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="None"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
     </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
            allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
              enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <!--kind="webHttpEndpoint"-->
      <endpoint address="https://localhost:1111/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
          name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" endpointConfiguration="NoValidationBehavior2"/>
    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

could somebody help me ?!

P.S. sorry for my english

Comment: For starters, I see NoValidationBehavior and NoValidationBehavior2. Can you clear that up?

Comment: it is just misprint
it should be NoValidationBehavior and NoValidationBehavior

If i put comment  <!--kind="webHttpEndpoint"--> into endpoint tag then raise configurationErrorsException with message "The endpoint at standardEndpoints/webHttpEndpoint does not have a configured endpoint named 'NoValidationBehavior'. This is an invalid value for endpointConfiguration. " 
????

Comment: maybe it is related with some new features in WCF 4.0 !?

Answer (score 1):

I think we have solved it on [msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/53e9d387-fef6-463b-b9e8-356be3e4605f/#71b9155e-af79-4c59-a86d-ddaa0627b4e8). For your comment question: endpointConfiguration and kind attributes indeed relates to WCF 4.0. It relates to new feature called standardEndpoints which allows definition of "endpoint templates".